# how to declare Class.class with valid generics

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

Note: purely out of curiosity and not for any actual use case.

I'm wondering if there is a way to declare the `Class` `Class` object with valid type parameters:

```
Class cc1 = Class.class; //raw type
Class<Class> cc2 = Class.class; //now parameter is raw type
Class<Class<?>> cc3 = Class.class; //compile error: inconvertible types
```

If `Class` and `Class<?>` are interchangeable, why are `Class<Class>` and `Class<Class<?>>` not?

**EDIT:** the question can be generalized to an issue of nested raw type parameters. For example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> lst = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(); //same compile error
```

**EDIT2:** I should rephrase the question a little: I know that

```
Class<?> c = Class.class;
```

is valid but I'm wondering why `Class<Class>` is not the same as `Class<Class<?>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics have some pretty serious limitations. In this case you can't assign a type to the inner type of `Class<Class>` because you're actually referencing the raw type, not an implementation of the raw type. It will give you a warning, but you have no way to fix that warning.

`Class<Class<?>>` by itself isn't an inconvertible type, you just can't assign a class directly to it because it doesn't have the type `Class<Class<T>>`, it has the type `Class<T>`.

Think of it another way; try `List<List<String>>`. To create that, you need to create a List that takes a List of Strings. This works because lists can contain lists.

A Class is more like a primitive than a data object, so I don't think it'd be possible to create a Class that is of type Class of something else.

**Edit**: your extra question about `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>` is a more obvious example of the inconvertible type issue you're having with `Class<Class<?>>`.

Comment: The above answers gave detailed explanations of generics/wildcards, but this one got closest to what I was asking, which is why Class<Class> is not the same as Class<Class<?>>. Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of difficult to see exactly what you're asking (or what you're trying to do).. but you can parametrize without raw types.

```
Class<? extends Object> cc4 = Class.class; // no raw types
Class<?> cc5 = Class.class; // also an option
```

As far as your last example is concerned, it makes no sense because it appears you want to make an array list of array lists that hold `?`, but your declaration isn't declaring an array list of array lists that hold `?`.

Properly written (but still not proper Java) would be:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> lst = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); // Type mismatch
```

Which is expected. It doesn't work for the same reason something like the following doesn't work:

```
Object o = new Object();
Integer i = new Integer(3);

o = i;
i.floatValue();
o.floatValue(); // can't access that method, we need to specifically cast it to Integer
```

Java types aren't proactively inferred (even in an inheritance chain).

If you want to keep the wildcard in there, you're welcome to, though:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> lst = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>(); // works!
```

Comment: Perfect answer. But I need to point out that `<? extends Object>` is exactly the same thing as `<?>`, that is the only reason the expression matches.

Answer (score 2):

The rule here is that the generic type in the left side must match the generic type in the right side.

`Class<?>` means a class of any type.

```
Class<?> c = Class.class;
```

Works because Class of any type can be `Class<Class>`.

```
Class<Class<?>> cc3 = Class.class;
```

Do not work because Class.class type is `Class<Class>` which is not of type `Class<Class<?>>`

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> lst = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>();
```

Works because the two expressions match.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> lst = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

Don't match.