# Java Generics Hell

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I suspect this has been asked here (and answered) before, but I don't know how to name the problem.  Why can I express the wildcards without problem only when I'm not passing the class itself?

It all boils down to this code.  Everything works as expected except for the call to `genericsHell(ShapeSaver.class)`:

```
interface Shape { }

interface Circle extends Shape { }

interface ShapeProcessor<T extends Shape> { }

class CircleDrawer implements ShapeProcessor<Circle> { } 

class ShapeSaver<T extends Shape> implements ShapeProcessor<T> { }

class Test {
    void genericsHeaven(ShapeProcessor<? extends Shape> a) {}

    void genericsHell(Class<? extends ShapeProcessor<? extends Shape>> a) {}

    void test() {
        genericsHeaven(new CircleDrawer());
        genericsHeaven(new ShapeSaver<Circle>());
        genericsHell(CircleDrawer.class);
        genericsHell(ShapeSaver.class); // ERROR: The method genericsHell is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ShapeSaver>)
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope someone can explain this in English.  I'm pretty sure it's related to the [Covariance](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html) issue, meaning that assigning `ShapeSaver` to a generic `ShapeProcessor` could lead to a runtime exception.  But I'm not certain of the details.

Comment: Yes I'm really curious to hear this one explained. Love the title. Echoes my experiences on the matter :)

Comment: +1 reminds me of this question I asked a while back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065998/how-to-declare-class-class-with-valid-generics - it may be a similar issue of information being lost through the use of `.class`

Comment: I love the title of this question. Someone could write a book with that title.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The type of `ShapeSaver.class` is `Class<ShapeSaver>`. When feed it to `genericsHell()`, compiler needs to check if `Class<ShapeSaver>` is a subtype of `Class<? extends ShapeProcessor<?>`, which is reduces to whether `ShapeSaver` is a subtype of `ShapeProcessor<?>`. The subtype relation does not hold, the method call fails.

The same thing should be true for @Bohemian's solution. Here the subtype checking occurs at bound checking of `T` after `T` is inferred. It should fail too. This appears to be a compiler bug, which somehow misinterprets the rule that `Raw` is assignable to `Raw<X>` as if `Raw` is a subtype of `Raw<X>`. see also [Enum.valueOf throws a warning for unknown type of class that extends Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042424/enum-valueof-throws-a-warning-for-unknown-type-of-class-that-extends-enum)

A simple solution to your problem is to declare

```
void genericsHell(Class<? extends ShapeProcessor> a)
```

indeed, `ShapeSaver` is a subtype of `ShapeProcessor`, and the call compiles.

That's not just a workaround. There's a good reason for it. Strictly speaking, for any `Class<X>`, `X` must be a raw type. For example, `Class<List>` is ok, `Class<List<String>>` is not. Because there is really no class that represents `List<string>`; there is only a class representing `List`.

Ignore the stern warning that you shall not use raw type. We must use raw types sometimes, given how Java type system is designed. Even Java's core APIs (`Object.getClass()`) use raw types.

---

You probably intended to do something like this

```
genericsHell(ShapeSaver<Circle>.class);
```

Unfortunately, that's not allowed. Java could have, but did not, introduce type literal along with generics. That created lots of problems for lots of libraries. `java.lang.reflect.Type` is a mess and unusable. Every library has to introduce their own representation of type system to solve the problem.

You can borrow one, e.g. from Guice, and you'll be able to

```
genericsHell( new TypeLiteral< ShapeSaver<Circle> >(){} )
                               ------------------
```

(learn to skip the craps around `ShaveSaver<Circle>` when reading the code)

In the method body of `genericsHell()`, you'll have full type information, not just the class.

Comment: great - this answer deserves upvotes as it really builds on Bohemian's *how* and finally gets at the *why*. (unfortunately I was just vox populied)

Comment: @irreputable, thanks so much for the detailed explanation.  This question, perhaps not so unsurprisingly, is actually the result of my use of Guice.  I am really hoping I'm going to avoid all of this ugliness when I soon begin the jump to Scala.

Comment: @irreputable, if you wouldn't mind adding the appropriate Guice function declaration to your answer: genericsHell(TypeLiteral<? extends ShapeProcessor<? extends Shape>> typeLiteral)

Answer (score 11):

Typing the `genericsHell` method allows it to compile:

```
static <T extends ShapeProcessor<?>> void genericsHell(Class<T> a) {}
```

EDITED: This allows the compiler to specify from context, or by coding an explicit type, that the `ShapeProcessor` is not literally *any* `ShapeProcessor`, but the *same* type as the one passed as a parameter. If the call was explicitly typed, (which the compiler does under the covers) the code would look like this:

```
MyClass.<ShapeSaver>genericsHell(ShapeSaver.class);
```

Which interestingly, gives a type *warning*, but still compiles. The explicit type is not required however because sufficient type information is available from the parameter to [infer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html) the generic type.

Your question is missing some declarations, so I added them in to create a [Short Self-Contained Correct Example](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) - ie this code compiles as-is

```
static interface Shape { }

static interface Circle extends Shape { }

static interface ShapeProcessor<T extends Shape> { }

static class CircleDrawer implements ShapeProcessor<Circle> { }

static class ShapeSaver<T extends Shape> implements ShapeProcessor<T> { }

static void genericsHeaven(ShapeProcessor<? extends Shape> a) { }

// The change was made to this method signature:
static <T extends ShapeProcessor<?>> void genericsHell(Class<T> a) { }

static void test() {
    genericsHeaven(new CircleDrawer());
    genericsHeaven(new ShapeSaver<Circle>());
    genericsHell(CircleDrawer.class);
    genericsHell(ShapeSaver.class);
}
```

Comment: So why is typing the method necessary?

Comment: +1 took me a while, but makes sense, esp. after reading the linked article. So typing the method allows the compiler to infer a raw type, which loses the nested type information that it cannot verify. To illustrate, after typing the method, the following call causes the original error: `MyClass.<ShapeSaver<?>>genericsHell(ShapeSaver.class)` (note the nested `<?>`)

Comment: nice suggestion and especially for sscce +1